# How can i do this chart in react?

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I need to do this chart in reactjs. You can see its have a background, and lines are gradient. Can i do this in react-chartjs and how?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 1):

you can install this pakage [chart js 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2) and custome this